# SonarQube Configuration failed

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, cicd

> [[1;31mERROR[m] Failed to execute goal
> [32morg.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.10.0.2594:sonar[m
> [1m(default-cli)[m on project [36mCalculator[m: [1;31mYou're not
> authorized to analyze this project or the project doesn't exist on
> SonarQube and you're not authorized to create it. Please contact an
> administrator.[m -> [1m[Help 1]
> [m [[1;31mERROR[m]
> [[1;31mERROR[m] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the [1m-e[m
> switch.
> [[1;31mERROR[m] Re-run Maven using the [1m-X[m switch to
> enable full debug logging.
> [[1;31mERROR[m]
> [[1;31mERROR[m] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
> [[1;31mERROR[m] [1m[Help 1][m http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
> [0m[0m [Pipeline] } WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succeed?

I am using SonarQube Community Edition Version 10.3. In this version, I am encountering an authentication issue. When I use an older version of SonarQube, everything works fine. However, with this specific version, I am facing problems. I am running SonarQube from Jenkins. Does anyone have any ideas on why I am experiencing this issue? Do I need to take additional steps to handle authentication?

Comment: "**You're not authorized to analyze this project or the project doesn't exist on SonarQube and you're not authorized to create it**"  How is anyone going to help you with that?  We,  the readers on SO, doe not know anything about **your** project....

Comment: A solution might be found here (on community.sonarsource.com):  [ERROR: You’re not authorized to run analysis. Please contact the project administrator](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/error-you-re-not-authorized-to-run-analysis-please-contact-the-project-administrator/98532)

Comment: "To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch"  Did you do that ?  Also the  [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException)  claims that this problem is from a plugin...